# Префиксы у идентификаторов, template, мультиметод

Tags: c++

1. Как работают указатели?
   перенесено [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/486816/178576).
2. Что значат эти приставки перед названием переменных? `b | h | d | i | m | p`
   Перенесено [сюда.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/486828)
3. Что такое `LPVOID`, `LPARAM`, `LPSTR` и все остальные?
   перенесено [сюда.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/486824)
4. что такое `template`?
   перенесено [сюда.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/486831)
5. Как создать некий мультиметод?

   Чтобы я мог написать, например:

   ```
   int Method(int a, int b, int c)
   {

   }
   ```

   указать, например, только один аргумент, и чтобы компилятор не сообщал об ошибке. Т.е., замена:

   ```
   int Method(int a)
   {

   }

   int Method(int a, int b)
   {

   }

   int Method(int a, int b, int c)
   {

   }
   ```

Comment: Это 5 отдельных, несвязанных вопросов. Задавайте их по отдельности.

Comment: дополню VladD: количество сообщений типа «вопрос» (которые можно создать с помощью кнопки «задать вопрос» в правом верхнем углу страницы) **не ограничено** (конечно, в пределах разумного). а вот внутри такого сообщения должен быть **один** вопрос (в крайнем случае — больше одного, если они **все** тесно взаимосвязаны).

Comment: Не ограничено, но с временным ограничением, 1 тема раз в 5 минут.
И мне не хочется засорять кучей вопросов, просто вопросы из разряда C++ вот и не хотелось создавать кучу тем.
Да и 5 вопросов, я смогу задать через 25 минут(точнее закончу)
И хочется получить ответы сразу, что бы не потеряться в темах своих же.

Comment: Указатель - это переменная, хранящая адрес каких-то данных в памяти. Звездочка используется при определении указателя и для получения данных, на которые ссылается указатель. Про WinAPI надо читать книгу Рихтера "Профессиональное программирование под винду".

Comment: @CHBS, этот сайт — не столько площадка для ответов на вопросы, сколько база знаний (да, она формируется из вопросов и ответов). и те, кто отвечает на вопросы, делают это не столько из желания помочь **кому-то лично**, сколько из желания сформировать базу знаний, и помочь **многим** людям, которые впоследствии будут искать ответы на возникшие у них вопросы.

Comment: @CHBS, сейчас уже, конечно, поздно, но в будущем постарайтесь, пожалуйста, помогать не только себе, но и другим людям, которые впоследствии будут искать ответы на такие же вопросы, которые возникли у вас. в частности: задавайте по **одному** вопросу «за раз».

Comment: Я понял вас.
Все таки мне пересоздавать темы с 3 и 4 вопросами?

Comment: @CHBS, мне кажется, это не плохая идея. хотя, конечно, уже немного поздновато. в общем, на ваше усмотрение.

Comment: Пожалуй все вопросы, кроме 3 (Windows-specific) отвечаются чтением книжки по языку C++. (SODD) SO driving development в действии :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) (*перенесено [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/486821/10105)*.)

2) Насчёт большинства это вы загнули. Такой метод именования переменных называется «венгерская нотация», он уже давно устарел за исключением, пожалуй, префикса `m_`. Идея была в том, чтобы название переменной отображало ещё и её тип. Префикс `b` означал, что переменная реально имеет тип `BOOL`, `h` — что `HANDLE`, `d` — `DOUBLE`, `i` — `INT`, `p` — что указатель. Префикс `m_` означал, что это поле (member) какой-нибудь структуры или класса. Префиксы можно было комбинировать, например, поле класса, являющееся указателем на `int`, называлось как-нибудь `m_piAge`.

5) Проще всего, вероятно, с аргументами по умолчанию.

```
int f(int a, int b = 0, int c = 0)
{
    // ...
}
```

Здесь если вы не укажете третий аргумент, он будет считаться равным 0. Или если не укажете второй и третий, то они оба будут считаться равными нулю.

Comment: Больше спасибо за столь развернутый ответ.

Comment: VladD, может быть, перенесёте ответ на первый пункт в [этот вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/486816/178576)? а из данного вопроса хотя бы первый удалим.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: Готово!

Comment: @VladD, спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

1. Первое указатель, а второе - нет.
2. Какое ещё большинство?? Это называется [венгерской нотацией](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F). Бред.
3. typedef'ы или define'ы для некоторых типов, применяемых в winapi. Наведи мышку в VS и посмотри конкретнее.
4. Шаблонная функция. Весьма жирный вопрос, не хочу тут отвечать.
5. Как у тебя, только с именем. А ещё можно использовать значения по умолчанию.

Comment: Qwertiy, может быть, перенесёте ответ на первый пункт в [этот вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/486816/178576)? а из данного вопроса хотя бы первый удалим.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, а смысл ответ из одного предложения переносить?

Comment: автор вопроса решился разбить вопрос на отдельные пункты. мне кажется, имеет смысл ответить на каждое из сообщений отдельно, а здесь «лишнее» удалить.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, но отвечать одним предложением на отдельный вопрос - это как-то не очень...

Comment: можно отвечать, например, двумя.