# Как работают указатели?

Tags: c++

Как работают указатели?

Что будет в итоге, если я напишу так?

```
HANDLE * VariableHandle;
DWORD * VariableDword;
```

или так?

```
HANDLE VariableHandle;
DWORD VariableDword;
```

Пример из исходных кодов других программ.

Почему так?

```
int chSizeOfArray(char *chArray);
int iSizeOfArray(int *iArray);
```

А не так?

```
int chSizeOfArray(char chArray);
int iSizeOfArray(int iArray);
```

Comment: Недавно [статью по указателям](http://scrutator.me/post/2015/11/26/pointers_demystified_p1.aspx) написал, как раз для новичков.

Comment: @ixSci: Вот ещё отличная статья (но на английском): http://ericlippert.com/2014/05/12/what-are-the-fundamental-rules-of-pointers/

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35015/discussion-on-question-by-chbs---).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Когда вы пишете `HANDLE * VariableHandle;`, вы объявляете, что в переменной `VariableHandle` будет содержаться *указатель* на `HANDLE`. А объявление `HANDLE VariableHandle;` означает, что в переменной `VariableHandle` будет содержаться сам `HANDLE`.

В языках типа C указатель используется во многих смыслах. Один из них — это *массив* элементов. Функции `int f1(char *chArray);` и `int f2(char ch);` обе возможны, но при этом `f1` принимает в качестве аргумента *массив* `char`'ов (или *указатель* на один `char`, это уж как в документации написано), а `f2` — один `char`.

---

Как верно подсказывает @ixSci, лучше всего думать про указатель как про *адрес* объекта. Если представить себе всю память как огромный массив байт, адрес — это просто номер начального байта, занимаемого данными, в этом массиве. (Это несколько упрощённая картина, но для начала то, что нужно.)

Comment: Еще раз огромное спасибо вам за столь развернутый ответ ;)

Comment: @CHBS: Пожалуйста! ;-)

Comment: @CHBS, 1. можно проголосовать за вопросы и ответы (треугольная стрелка вверх слева от вопроса/ответа). 2. автор вопроса может отметить наиболее исчерпывающий ответ «принятым» («галочка» слева от ответа).

Comment: @VladD, в переменной VariableHandle будет содержаться _адрес_ чего-то, а не указатель. Указатель это и есть переменная, которая содержит адрес.

Comment: @ixSci: Адрес, насколько мне помнится, не упомянут в стандарте. Хуже того, некоторые компиляторы/платформы содержат в некоторых типах указателей не реальный адрес, а что-то другое.

Comment: @VladD, вполне возможно, что нет — не упомянут, но лучше использовать именно адрес, т.к. говорить, что  VariableHandle содержит указатель не верно,— не содержит. Содержит что-то, что позволяет переменной VariableHandle указывать на что-то другое. А «неадрес», обычно, содержат указатель на функции-члены. Поэтому, на мой взгляд, с изрядной долей упрощения, лучше использовать адрес и не морочить себе голову

Comment: @ixSci: Методологически вы правы, дополнил ответ.

Comment: @ixSci: Не обязательно функции-члены. [Отсюда](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040113-00/?p=41073): _A function pointer on the ia64 does not point to the first byte of code. Intsead, it points to a structure that describes the function. The first quadword in the structure is the address of the first byte of code, and the second quadword contains the value of the so-called “gp” register._

Comment: @ixSci: И предваряя ваш ответ, [The x86 architecture is the weirdo](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040914-00/?p=37873/).