# С++ LPVOID PCHAR каково их предназначение?

Tags: c++

В C++ есть основные типы-данных.

```
int  string  char  void  DWORD param
```

Но для чего нужны такие типы данных?

```
LPARAM LPVOID PCHAR LPCVOID LPDWORD WPARAM
```

Как они используются?
Каково собственно их предназначение?

Answer (score 7):

Начнём с основных типов данных в C++:

> int  string  char  void  DWORD param

`std::string` не является основным типом, а является специализацией шаблона `std::basic_string` из стандартной библиотеки, который, в свою очередь, не является базовым типом. `DWORD` не является C++ типом вообще. `param`, я так полагаю, это Вы по ошибке поставили, так? Кроме этих типов, в C++ есть ещё немало других. Почитайте книгу по C++, много нового узнаете.

Что касается других типов:

> LPARAM LPVOID PCHAR LPCVOID LPDWORD WPARAM

Это типы-псевдонимы, т.е. это какие-то базовые типы, которым дали другие имена. К примеру, я могу ввести новое имя для `int`:

```
typedef int SuperbType;
```

И везде использовать `SuperbType` вместо `int`. Для чего это делать? Для удобства — название типов больше соответствуют сфере их применения, а также несут в себя некоторую дополнительную информацию. Так, к примеру, `DWORD` означает двойное слово, что говорит нам, что этот тип будет всегда равен 4-м байтам. Соответствующий `typedef` гарантирует нам это как для 32-х битных, так и для 16-и битных систем(WinAPI это старая технология). Посмотреть, что реально скрывается за именами этих типов можно в заголовках WinAPI.

Answer (score 2):

```
LPARAM LPVOID PCHAR LPCVOID LPDWORD WPARAM
```

-- это всё псевдонимы стандартных типов, используемых *Microsoft* в *WinAPI*. Введены они для того, чтобы их размер всегда соответствовал требуемому (поскольку длина целых типов в *C/C++* нефиксирована), а также для улучшения читаемости и понимания (хотя это улучшение ещё большой вопрос...).

Так, например, для x86 эти типы имеют следующий вид:

```
typedef long           LONG_PTR;
typedef void          *LPVOID;
typedef char          *PCHAR;
typedef const void    *LPCVOID;
typedef unsigned long *LPDWORD;
typedef unsigned int   WPARAM;
```

Более подробно [на сайте M$](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

В дополнение к другим ответам:

`LPARAM` и `WPARAM` обычно используются в контексте `WindowProc` — оконных процедур. Это такие процедуры, которые «прикреплены» к каждому окну, и обрабатывают сообщения, которые этому окну посылает система (или другие процессы). Например, сообщения о движении мыши или об изменении размеров.

Процедура определена так:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(
  _In_ HWND   hwnd,
  _In_ UINT   uMsg,
  _In_ WPARAM wParam,
  _In_ LPARAM lParam
);
```

и принимает `HWND` — хэндл окна, `UINT`-параметр (номер [оконного сообщения](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644927%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#system_defined)), и два аргумента, один из которых число (обычно небольшой числовой параметр, какие-нибудь флаги и т. п.), а второй — длинное число (например, пара чисел, координаты) или указатель (на буфер). Точный смысл параметров зависит от типа сообщения.

Всё это имеет смысл лишь в WinAPI-программировании (низкоуровневое программирование под Windows Desktop). Современные системы/фреймворки обычно предоставляют вам более высокоуровневые абстракции. (Например, класс `CWnd` вместе хэндла `HWND` в MFC.)