# Почему большинство исходных кодов пишутся с маленькой буквой перед именем переменной?

Tags: c++, именование

Почему большинство исходных кодов пишутся в таком стиле?

```
    bVariable   
    hProcess  
    hVariable  
    dVariable  
    iMoney      
    m_BasePtr  
    pLock
```

Что значат эти приставки?
`b | h | d | i | m | p`

Comment: это неправда, никакое _большинство_ исходных кодов так не пишется. Есть много старого кода по WinAPI с такой нотацией, это правда, но это далеко от «большинства»

Comment: @ixSci легаси...оно такое )

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Это [венгерская нотация](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F):

- b - boolean
- h - хендлер/дескриптор
- d - double (если для типа), delta (если для задания смысла)
- i - integer (если для типа), индекс/итератор (если для задания смысла)
- m - для свойств класса
- p - указатель

Comment: То, что Вы назвали `свойствами`, на самом деле `члены`. В `C++` нет такого понятия как `свойство класса`.

Comment: у С++ нету свойства, но есть член - как иронично (((