# Что такое template, как и зачем?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

1. Что такое template в C++?
2. Для каких целей он используется?
3. Как он используется? - Желательно бы пример использования.

Comment: Прочтайте книжку, любую по C++, хотя бы: https://books.google.ru/books?id=ixxYPzpL3mYC&pg=PA23&dq=%D0%AF%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA++C%2B%2B&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiniKyipMvKAhXEvXIKHTw3Dlg4FBDoAQh3MBM#v=onepage&q=%D0%AF%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%20%20C%2B%2B&f=false а вот более детально: https://books.google.ru/books?id=tGUc3-GPRVwC&pg=PA231&dq=%D0%AF%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA++C%2B%2B&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwimhpCvpMvKAhWBjXIKHdYSBzE4KBDoAQgbMAA#v=onepage&q=%D0%AF%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%20%20C%2B%2B&f=false

Comment: Уууух, вот это вопрос =D

Comment: Читайте книги, это слишком большой вопрос.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Шаблоны (template) в *C++* являются отдельными синтаксическими конструкциями.

Шаблоны используются для обобщённого программирования. Вы пишете алгоритм, который работает с различными типами данных, требуя от них только некоторой небольшой функциональности, а компилятор при использовании этого шаблона с конкретным типом подставляет тип и фактически сам генерирует требуемый код на *C++*.

Вот простейший пример использования шаблонов:

```
template<typename T> T min(const T x, const T y) {
    return x < y ? x : y;
}
```

Мы написали код, который работает с любым типом данных, требуя от этого типа только наличия операции "меньше" (operator<). (На самом деле ещё конструктора копирования, но это уже детали.) Теперь мы можем использовать наш шаблон:

```
int x, y;
int z = min(x,y);  // Автоматический вывод типа.
double a, b;
double c = min(a,b);  // Автоматический вывод типа.
double d = min<double>(x,y);  // Явное указание типа.

std::vector::iterator i, j, k;
k = min(i,j);
```

Видно, что нам удалось использовать этот шаблон не только к обычным числовым типам, но и к сложным сущностям - итераторам.

В этом мощь обобщённого программирования - код, написанный один раз используется многократно. Но есть и недостаток - "разбухание" бинарного кода - для каждого типа параметра шаблона компилятор создаст свой бинарный код.

Comment: Типы параметров хорошо бы сделать `const T&`, для `std::vector` указать тип хранимых данных, и инициализировать переменные перед их использованием (предположу, что иначе возможен UB), не смотря на то, что это всего лишь пример.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ, очень мне помог
Это грубо говоря три метода которые принимают типы аргументов по разному.
Шаблонизатор для методов.